# Multiple lists to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have three list here

`[1,2,3,4,5]`

`[5,4,6,7,2]`

`[1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]`

I want this kind of output:

```
A     B    C
1     5    1
2     4    2
3     6    4
4     7    5
5     2    6
           7
           8
           9
           0
```

I tried one syntax , but it gives me this  error `arrays must all be same length` and another error was `Length of values does not match length of index`

Is there any way to get this kind of output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not easily supported, but it can be done. `DataFrame.from_dict` will with the "index" orient. Assuming your lists are `A`, `B`, and `C`:

```
pd.DataFrame([A, B, C]).T

     0    1    2
0  1.0  5.0  1.0
1  2.0  4.0  2.0
2  3.0  6.0  4.0
3  4.0  7.0  5.0
4  5.0  2.0  6.0
5  NaN  NaN  7.0
6  NaN  NaN  8.0
7  NaN  NaN  9.0
8  NaN  NaN  0.0
```

---

Another option is using `DataFrame.from_dict`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A' : A, 'B' : B, 'C' : C}, orient='index').T

     A    B    C
0  1.0  5.0  1.0
1  2.0  4.0  2.0
2  3.0  6.0  4.0
3  4.0  7.0  5.0
4  5.0  2.0  6.0
5  NaN  NaN  7.0
6  NaN  NaN  8.0
7  NaN  NaN  9.0
8  NaN  NaN  0.0
```

---

A third solution with `zip_longest` and `DataFrame.from_records`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
pd.DataFrame.from_records(zip_longest(A, B, C), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
# pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(zip_longest(A, B, C)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

     A    B  C
0  1.0  5.0  1
1  2.0  4.0  2
2  3.0  6.0  4
3  4.0  7.0  5
4  5.0  2.0  6
5  NaN  NaN  7
6  NaN  NaN  8
7  NaN  NaN  9
8  NaN  NaN  0
```

Comment: Interestingly the last method is the fastest, probably the lack of transposing removes the intermediary structure +1

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for the timings! Happy to see you answering, have already returned the vote :)

Comment: @coldspeed thanks took a break from answering, not too many interesting and new questions IMO, mainly performing cleanup duties. Also very busy at work, always interesting to browse questions occassionally

Comment: @Coder I found yet another solution, I've added it at the top.

Answer (score 4):

alternative is to perform a list comprehension of a `Series` of each list and construct a df from this:

```
In[61]:
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(x) for x in [A,B,C]], index=list('ABC')).T
df

Out[61]: 
     A    B    C
0  1.0  5.0  1.0
1  2.0  4.0  2.0
2  3.0  6.0  4.0
3  4.0  7.0  5.0
4  5.0  2.0  6.0
5  NaN  NaN  7.0
6  NaN  NaN  8.0
7  NaN  NaN  9.0
8  NaN  NaN  0.0
```

### timings:

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(x) for x in [A,B,C]], index=list('ABC')).T
%timeit pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A' : A, 'B' : B, 'C' : C}, orient='index').T
from itertools import zip_longest
%timeit pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(zip_longest(A, B, C)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

1.23 ms ± 12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
977 µs ± 1.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
545 µs ± 8.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So the last method is the fastest

Answer (score 0):

An idea for a custom way.

Define a couple of methods to adjust the input data:

```
def longest(*lists):
  return max([ len(x) for x in lists])

def equalize(col, size):
  delta = size - len(col)
  if delta == 0: return col
  return col + [None for _ in range(delta)]
```

To be used building the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

size = longest(col1, col2, col3)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':equalize(col1, size), 'b':equalize(col2, size), 'c':equalize(col3, size)})
```

Which returns

```
     a    b  c
0  1.0  5.0  1
1  2.0  4.0  2
2  3.0  6.0  4
3  4.0  7.0  5
4  5.0  2.0  6
5  NaN  NaN  7
6  NaN  NaN  8
7  NaN  NaN  9
8  NaN  NaN  0
```